# Create Bar-chart with plotly where data is a categorical array

Tags: javascript, plotly

I'm a total newbie on javascript and have issues to create a barchart based on data which is a categorical array.

Could somebody help me to point out how I create a bar chart using plotly.
The main problem is to create the x and y data arrays for me.

My Data looks like this:

```js
tableData = {}
column = "Sex"
data = ['male','female', 'male', 'male','male','male','male','male','male','male', 'male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male']

console.log(data)



tableData = {}
column = "Sex"
data = ['male','female', 'male', 'male','male','male','male','male','male','male', 'male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male']

tableData[column] = data



var data = [
  {
    x: ???
    y:???
    type: 'bar'
  }
];

Plotly.newPlot('test', data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a question about Plotly but more about counting how often a value appears in a JavaScript array. There are various ways to achieve this, my favourite one is with `reduce()`:

```
let tableData = data.reduce(function(obj, val) {
   obj[val] = ++obj[val] || 1;
   return obj;
}, {});
```

This creates an object (tableData) where all unique strings of your array (data) appear as key and their frequency as value, i.e.

```
{ male: 31, female: 12 }
```

Putting it together with your code, you will end up with:

```js
let data = ['male','female', 'male', 'male','male','male','male','male','male','male', 'male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male','male','female', 'male']

let tableData = data.reduce(function(obj, val) {
  obj[val] = ++obj[val] || 1;
  return obj;
}, {});


let plotData = [
  {
    x: Object.keys(tableData),
    y: Object.values(tableData),
    type: 'bar'
  }
];

Plotly.newPlot('test', plotData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
```